# I get error SQL

Tags: php, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stats' WHERE `ip` = '::1' && `date` = '28-11-2013'' at line 1.

```
 <?php

 require_once 'includes/config.php';

 $getStats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'stats' WHERE `ip` = '" . $ip . "' && `date` = '" . $time ."'") or die(mysql_error());

 if( mysql_num_rows($getStats) == 0)
 {
    $select = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stats` (`ip`,`data`,`hits`,`online`) VALUES ('" . $ip . "','" . $time . "', '1', '" . $timestamp ."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
     }
else
{
    $select = mysql_query("UPDATE `stats` SET `hits` = `hits`+1, `online` = '" . $timestamp . "' WHERE `ip` = '" . $ip . "' && `date` = '" . $time . "'");
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: this problem will solved but another problem will come . This is new problem Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL [quotes identifiers with a backtick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) like **`stats`**, and *not* like **'stats'** - which is what causes the syntax error.

Either remove the useless identifier quote ([stats is not reserved](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html)) or switch to proper identifier quotes.

The subsequent issue is that there *is no `data` column*, which is just as the error says. The correct column is probably `date` (which should be quoted, or perhaps renamed).

Also, dates should be supplied in the form of ['YYYY-MM-DD' (or variant)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html). The fact that the query works with a locale-specific date makes me believe a proper [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) column is not used as it ought to be. Correcting the column type now will avoid issues in the future, especially with sorting.

---

In *addition* to the above corrections, also [update the query to use mysqli/PDO and placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) - this will tidy up the code, eliminate the use of deprecated functions, and prevent SQL injection (accidental or otherwise).

Comment: this problem will solved but another problem will come . This is new problem Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3036848 Also make sure the `\`date\`` column has the appropriate data-type: `DATE`. Otherwise you'll run into different issues, such as "incorrectly" ordered data. I've added an appropriate section to my answer.

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1412470_733414666686841_128887452_o.jpg , @user2864740

Comment: @user3036848 Then put in the *correct value*. The code is putting in `timestamp`, which is probably a Unix time value. Note that the `hits` column already records 1..2..3..etc.